# RESET invoice no every year

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print invoice *no* as *2048/18-19, 1/19-20*, where *2048* is the invoice *no* and *18-19* is session. 
I can print the session, I can even print the bill *no* using `SELECT count()`, but the problem is if the invoice is opened from 2 different tabs/machine they will get the same invoice *no* at a time.

I just want to know how implement this thing. I want the logic. I don't know how to implement locking. It will great if you provide good locking tutorials along with this.

Comment: Could you please share us your code? Others are more likely to help you, if they know what you already tried.

Comment: i don't know how to implement this logic. Previously i was using auto increment to generate bill no.

Comment: Ok i found a solution,  Using composite primary key using AI